# Showing only changes from a particular author using change package

Tags: changes, trackchanges

I would like to know if it is possible to show changes made from a particular author only, using the the `changes` package?

```
I am a \replaced[id=ann]{girl}{boy}. You are a \replaced[id=peter]{boy}{girl}.
```

I wonder if there is any switch so that the PDF generated only marks changes made by `ann`, while all changes made by peter are accepted.

As an additional question, is it possible to set it so that I can mark changes made by `ann`, while all changes made by peter are **NOT** made?

Thanks!

Comment: Good idea, would be worth an e-mail to the maintainer of the changes package.